# How to group by a Variable A to get a minimum value from Variable B based on a condition on Variable C

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data of 3 variables A, B, C. I need to group by on A and need a minimum value of B when C is non-zero.

```
> data
     A       B       C
1    a       3       0
2    a       6       1
3    a       9       2
4    a       12      2
5    b       3       0
6    b       6       0
7    b       9       0
8    b       12      4
```

Expected Output:

```
> output
     1       2
1    a       6       
2    b       12
```

I tried doing this which was running for more than 2 hours:

```
rbind(by(data, data$A, function(x) min(x$B[x$C>0])))
```

Comment: `aggregate(B~A, df[df$C != 0,], min)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'A', get the `min` of 'B' where 'C' is not 0

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(A) %>% 
   summarise(B = min(B[C > 0]))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  A         B
#   <chr> <int>
#1 a         6
#2 b        12
```

Or a faster option would be to `filter` first, then do the `group_by`

```
df1 %>%
   filter(C > 0) %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   summarise(B = min(B))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(B = min(B[C > 0])) , A]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
B = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 12L), C = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```